# Issues using Localize.js and AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

Localize.js is causing problems when trying to translate contents included in an ng-repeat element.

The content that should be translated, is simply removed. No errors in the console.

The only way I found to make it working is putting 
    Localize.setLanguage()
within the Angular controller managing the content to be translated, and only there.

The point is that (for some specific reasons) I need to put Localize.setLanguage() before that point.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Edit - this is the relevant code:**

This script is in the HTML head:

```
    <script>
        Localize.initialize({
            key: 'xxxxxxxx',
            rememberLanguage: false,
            saveNewPhrases: false,
            translateTitle: true,
            translateBody: true
        });
        Localize.setLanguage('en');
    </script>
```

where, 'en' is not the default language in Localize.js (which is 'it').

And this is the HTML in the body:

```
    <b ng-repeat="f in filtri" ng-cloak>
        <span class="filter__label filter__label--key">{{f.l}}</span><span class="filter__label filter__label--value" notranslate>{{f.v}}</span>
    </b>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I've edited the quesiton to add the relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: hey @Ste83, happy to help do you mind pinging us over at support@localizejs.com so we can dig in to debug this issue. It may be with the way angular is appending and removing content using ng-repeat.

Comment: thanks for replying! we are now in contact with your support team. thanks.